# How can I pass the data from a POST request to my global state with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, state

I have a submit button for my form, which, on submit makes a POST request that responds with some data. I would like to pass this data from the POST request to a globalized state. This is what I have so far:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { startLoading, stopLoading, contextualize } from './actions'

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    if (values.firm != '' && values.infosys != '' && values.spot != '') {
      console.log(values)
      const postData = async () => {
        const data = JSON.stringify({values})
        const result = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/form/', data)
        console.log(result.data)
      };
      postData()}
    }
```

```
import loadingReducer from './loading'
import contextReducer from './context'
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    isLoading: loadingReducer,
    contextReducer: contextReducer,
})

export default allReducers
```

**I want contextualize action to handle setting the POST data as a global state.**

```
export const contextualize = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'CONTEXTUALIZE'
    }
}
```

**How can I get the data from the action into my reducer below to set the global state for my app?**

```
const contextReducer = (state=null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CONTEXTUALIZE':
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default contextReducer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data from an action to a reducer by adding a `payload` key to the object that your action returns:

```
export const contextualize = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'CONTEXTUALIZE',
        payload: data
    }
}
```

Then just adjust your reducer to return the payload:

```
const contextReducer = (state=null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CONTEXTUALIZE':
            return action.payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Now you have an action that passes data to a reducer, and in turn updates the global state.